# CFileHelper::findFiles method stops when array is empty

Tags: file, yii

I'm using CFileHelper::findFiles() method to list all files under a specific directory. it works correctly when the directory is not empty. but if there is no file under it, the method suddenly stops whit no error messages or exceptions. Is there any idea about this problem?

Edit :

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        /**
         * @var Supplier $supplier
         */
        $data = $this->getRequestData();
        $supplier = Supplier::model()->findByPk($data['id']);
        if (isset($supplier)) {
            $files = $supplier->getCertificateFilesList();
            $response = new LabResponse();
            $response->addRegion('certificates-wrapper', $this->renderPartial('partial/_thumbnails', array(
                'supplier' => $supplier,
                'files' => $files
            ), true));
            $this->sendHttpResponse(200, $response->getResponse());
        }
        $this->sendHttpResponse(404);
    }

public function getCertificateFilesList()
    {
        $dir = 'uploads/suppliers/certificates/11';
        $files = CFileHelper::findFiles($dir);
        return $files;
    }
```

Comment: If directory is empty it return empty array.

Comment: @naveengoyal so Why it stops in my code?

Comment: how you handle empty array in your code ? can you post that code?

Comment: I think when I called this method for empty folder it stuck on an infinite loop. because after the call apache won't response any more.

Comment: Can you please post the code that invokes this method and how your application works with the returned value.

Comment: @Martin I've posted my action code.